# event handlers and jquery .load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

I'm using ajax to insert additional content after a click.
Inside the content I'd like to react to another click event.
But unfortunately it doesn't work - the alert() isn't fired.

test.html

```
<button id="button_load">load text</button>
<div id="content"><!--content--></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#button_load").on("click", function(){ $("#content").load("test_content.html"); });
$("#button_hide").on("click", function(){ alert("hide text"); });
</script>
```

test_content.html

```
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<button id="button_hide">hide text</button>
```

Any idea what the problem might be or how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assignment of the `.on('click')` happens at runtime, when the HTML its assigning to does not exist yet. You can do one of two things:

**Assign in callback function after load**

```
$('#button_load').on('click',function(){
    $('#content').load('test_content.html',function(){
        $('#button_hide').on('click',function(){
            alert('hide text');
        });
    });
});
```

or **delegate your click handler**:

```
$('#button_load').on('click',function(){
    $('#content').load('test_content.html');
});

$('#content').on('click','#button_hide',function(){
    alert('hide text');
});
```

Delegation is usually preferred because it is less impact on the DOM and reusable, but up to you. If you go that direction, I'd leverage caching:

```
var $content = $('#content');

$('#button_load').on('click',function(){
    $content.load('test_content.html');
});

$content.on('click','#button_hide',function(){
    alert('hide text');
});
```

This way you only query the DOM once.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this line:

```
$("#button_hide").on("click", function(){ alert("hide text"); });
```

To this line:

```
$("#content").on("click", "#button_hide", function(){ alert("hide text"); });
```